# Sequence of events in a program?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript,

If I have the following, is `b` called after `a` has finished or not?

```
function main() {
    a();
    b();
}
function a() {
    //Processing
}
function b() {
    //More Processing
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that code, nothing happens at all, since none of the functions are actually called.

If the "main()" function were to be called, then it's guaranteed that the call to "a" would complete before the function "b" was initiated. In the context of a web browser, JavaScript is strictly single-threaded unless you're delving into the new-ish "web worker" capabilities.